# My Jtable is blank

Tags: swing, jtable, jframe, text-files

**SOLVED THANKS TO ALL WHO HELPED **

Hello my q is about a jtable that i have ,i fill it with components from a .txt ,I have a main (menu ) JFrame and by pressing a jbutton i want the jtable to pop out ! My problem is that my jtable is blank and it supposed to show some date !I would appreciated any help , Thanks.
this is my ''reading'' class`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     company Company=new company();
    payFrame jframe=new payFrame(Company);
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setSize(600,300);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
     readClass();
}
    //diavasma
  public static void readClass(){
    ArrayList<Employee> emp =new ArrayList<Employee>() ;
    //Employee[] emp=new Employee[7];
    //read from file
 try {

   int i=0;
   // int rowCounter;
   // int payments=0;

String inputDocument = ("src/Employees.txt");


FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputDocument);
Reader iD = new InputStreamReader(is);


BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(iD);
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] lineParts = inputLine.split(",");

            String email = (lineParts[7]);
            int EmpNo = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[0]);
            String type = lineParts[10];
            int PostalCode = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[5]);
            int phone = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[6]);
            int DeptNo = (short) Integer.parseInt(lineParts[8]);
            double Salary;
            int card = (short) Integer.parseInt(lineParts[10]);
            int emptype = 0;
             int hours=Integer.parseInt(lineParts[11]);
            if (type.equals("FULL TIME")) {
                emptype = 1;
            } else if (type.equals("SELLER")) {
                emptype = 2;
            } else {
                emptype = 3;
            }

            /**
             *  Creates employee instances depending on their type of employment
             *  (fulltime=1, salesman=2, parttime=3)
             */
            switch (emptype) {
                case 1:


                    Salary = Double.parseDouble(lineParts[10]);
                    emp.add(new FullTime(lineParts[1], lineParts[2], EmpNo, 
                            lineParts[3],
                            lineParts[4], PostalCode, phone,
                            email, DeptNo, card, Salary,hours, type));

                    i++;
                    break;
```

and this is my class where i make my Jtable and fill him

```
public class company extends JFrame {
    private ArrayList<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    public void addEmployee(Employee emplo) {

    emp.add(emplo);
}

public ArrayList<Employee> getArray() {
    return emp;
}

public  void getOption1() {

     ArrayList<Employee> employee = getArray();
    JTable table = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    table.setModel(model);
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[]{"Code", "First Name", "Last Name", "Address", "City", "Postal Code", "Phone", "Email",
                "Dept Code", "Salary", "Time Card", "Hours"});
    for (Employee current : employee) {
        model.addRow(new Object[]{current.getempCode(), current.getfirst(), current.getlast(),
                    current.getaddress(), current.getcity(), current.getpostalCode(),
                    current.gettelephone(), current.getemail(), current.getdep(),
                    current.getsalary(), current.getcardcode(), current.getHours()
                });

    }


    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane);
   setVisible(true);

    table.revalidate();
```

Comment: You have some serious editing to do in order to make your question readable.

Comment: help me im new in stackoverflow ask me what u need to know :) thanks   vlepw oti eiste elinas apla an mporesete na m pite estw pws mporw na dieukrinisw to prob mou euxaristw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot that could be improved about your code; in particular you should learn the Java naming conventions (Company instead of company; `company Company=new company();` is exactly backwards of how you should be declaring your variables).

Second, your class hierarchy doesn't make sense - is a company really a JFrame?  No.  You should have a Company class that holds the employees, and then a CompanyFrame class that extends the JFrame and has a reference to the Company object.

Third, you have not decomposed or isolated the problem.  There are any number of reasons your table might be blank.  Are you sure that your code reading the text file is working correctly?  Are you sure that the list of Employee objects is created correctly?  The easiest way to debug this stuff is to print out the state of your objects at various points in time and make assertions (e.g. `assert employee.size() > 0` if you expect there to be more than one employee at a given point.)

Finally, this goes for general programming - you have to be able to crawl before you can run.  In other words, don't start off trying to get everything working completely on the first pass.  Before you deal with reading the employees from files, make sure you can get it working with some hardcoded employee objects that you create yourself, within code.

Edit:

One clue is that you read your employees in a public static void method:

```
public static void readClass(){
    ArrayList<Employee> emp =new ArrayList<Employee>() ;
```

where do you ever add those employees into the employee arraylist in your frame?  You have an addEmployee method but it doesn't seem to be called

Comment: about the company Company yeah i know i had to write it backwards.   about my hierarchy ,im sure about the companies class i was using it without frames ,importing employees from my main (using constructors etc ) now instead of importing from my main i import them from a .txt and printing them in a jtable .:) thanks for the advices im new in java its my first semester in java yet :P

Comment: Yes you add the employees to your arraylist.  But that's not the same as adding it to the arraylist in your table model.  You should be calling addEmployee, not just .add.

Comment: yeah yeah i did it i call it and do more tricks i understand its difficult because you dont have all my project to get what i mean thanks anyway i solved it :D

Comment: If you solved it as a result of my help, then please check the box next to my answer and/or upvote my response so I get credit for taking time to help you.